# Remove sequential duplicates using regex (pipe delimited)

Tags: regex, duplicates, sequential, phrase, delimited

I have a pipe delimited list of phrases. I would like to remove sequential duplicates using a regex replace/substitution.  For example:

```
dog|cat|cat woman|cat woman|dog|dog 
cat|cat|catman|catman|catman|cat woman|cat woman|dog|dogman|doggy
```

would be transformed into

```
dog|cat|cat woman|dog 
cat|catman|cat woman|dog|dogman|doggy
```

I am stuck. So far, I am at
`((^|\|)([^\|]+))\1+` with a substitution of `$1`. But clearly, that does not work, for the output is

```
dog|cat woman|cat woman|dog 
cat|catman|catman|cat woman|dogman|doggy
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can set boundaries on the left and the right to prevent partial matches when using the capture group and the backreference.

If a lookbehind assertion is supported:

```
(?<![^|\n])([^|\n]+)(?:\|\1)+(?![^|\n])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<![^|\n])` Negative lookbehind, assert that what is directly to the left is not any char except `|` or a newline
- `([^|\n]+)` Capture group 1, match 1 or more times any char except `|` or a newline to prevent crossing lines
- `(?:\|\1)+` Repeat 1 or more times matching `|` and the backreference to group 1
- `(?![^|\n])` Negative lookahead that asserts that what is directly to the right is not any char except `|` or a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymwLDP/1)

In the replacement you can use capture group 1.

Output

```
dog|cat|cat woman|dog
cat|catman|cat woman|dog|dogman|doggy
```

With thanks to [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) for the great improvement.

Comment: If you don't put something to check what is on the left, you will get wrong results with something like `superman|man`. Also, you have to repeat the delimiter too.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I think the alternation in the repeating group would be better than the lookahead variant.

Comment: I will write it like this: https://regex101.com/r/jXkybt/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is awesome! It also accounts for `cat|cat` https://regex101.com/r/ymwLDP/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Are you going to post that solution?

Comment: No, because I'm too lazy.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Lazy or not, you have some reaaally good regex skills :-) I will update it with your gem.

Comment: First, thanks!
Second, what if lookbehind is not supported? Sadly, the application I am using this in does not support lookahead/lookbehind!

Comment: @hwm.nem: And this application is ? A possibility, you replace first each pipe with two pipes, you use [this substitution](https://regex101.com/r/3p9woK/1) then you replace back each two pipes sequence with a single pipe, and together these patterns will rule the galaxy as father and son.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: The software application is very industry specific. You would not be aware of it. Because of your comment, though, I decided to make a simple python function that can be called from the application, since it supports lookaround, and then I used your first method. THANK YOU!